# Python script to cut image into one square, then four squares, then eight

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am struggling to think of an efficient way to approach this. I need to read in an 80000x80000 pixel square image. I would like to cut this image into four connecting squares, and then eight connecting squares... and so on for as long as specified.

What's the best way of doing this using the PILLOW python library, not reading the image in every time?

Thanks

Comment: What format is the image?

Comment: The format is png - but can be converted to any more appropriate format.

Comment: I can't imagine python being able to handle a 20GB image. So you'll probably need to read over the image file and handle smaller sections individually. This should be possible with bmp files, but I'm not sure about png.

Comment: The file is about 2.3 gb

Comment: That's because png has decent compression. I think it would be ~20GB in RAM, plus more to process it. Have a look at [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/55978) (yours is about 10x larger).

Comment: I can run the script on a super computer, so RAM shouldn't be an issue. I just need to work out what the python script needs to say in order to achieve what I'm looking for. Cheers :P

Comment: How do you cut an 80000x80000 image into one square? It is already a square. Also, why not use ImageMagick?

Comment: All images would be resized to 256x256 pixels. I don't know how to use imagemagick but would be happy if it could be achieved by that.

Comment: My code so far is found below... I have made it cut the input picture into four quadrants but I don't know how to make it do 4, then 8, then 16, then 32 etc.                                                                http://pastebin.com/yWf6wMGZ